# Google ReCaptcha V2 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, recaptcha

I try to implement Google's ReCaptcha V2 on my website.

On validate captcha and submit my form I got that error (I replaced IP address) :

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php 
# https://github.com/google/recaptcha - 1.1.3
require_once('autoload.php');
if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {
    //  captcha
        $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($privatekey,new ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
        $class_captcha = ($resp->isSuccess() ? "ok" : "formerreur");
}
?>
<form name="myform" method="post"> 
    <span class="<?=$class_captcha?>">Anti spam</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>   
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="form_acces_ok" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">
</form>
```

This is very hard to debug because there is no messages in logs, no error in console, nothing that can help me.

I also want to clarify that this code is used in others of my websites and ReCaptcha works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, we've found the error : [nss crashing php-fpm process](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12935)
For this reason, the curlPost method used in Google's ReCaptcha cause php crash.

hope this help !!